# Is there any way in Android module to pick up resources from its own module and not from the app module?

Tags: android, gradle

I am creating an Android dependency library which will be packaged as an `AAR` file. The dependency will have `layouts`, `strings`, `dimens`, `images` etc. I created a sample demo project which includes this dependency.

Now consider the following scenario.

My library includes an `Image` file named `filter.png` and uses it inside a layout file.  The demo project also has an `Image` named `filter.png` but it is a different image. So when the project gets built, only the app's `filter.png` is picked up.  So even in my library's layout file, I am seeing the image used by the demo project.

As of now, I have changed the name and appended package name before every resource name to avoid the above scenario. 
But is there any way I can force Android to pick resources only from the current module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library will only have access to its own set of resources, but nothing can prevent the application from intentionally overriding the library's resources.

To prevent accidental overrides, you usually prefix your library resource names. For example, AppCompat uses the `abc_` prefix and the Design support library uses the `design_` prefix.

Furthermore, [you can explicitly declare which resources of your library are public](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources), so that the other ones will be private by default and if the app overrides them you will get a Lint warning.

Answer (score 2):

You app and library will have different package names, yes.

> As of now, I have changed the name and appended package name before every resource name to avoid the above scenario

And that is correct because resources are associated by package name.

`com.example.app.R.drawable.filter`  (Which is often just `R.drawable.filter`, *check your `import` statements!*), the current module.

vs some other module, `com.example.library.R.drawable.filter`

[Android - Accessing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

> `[<package_name>.]R.<resource_type>.<resource_name>`